# How to use imap_search() to return only unread messages without looping through each one?

Tags: php, imap, pop3

Because POP3 does not support the SEEN flags used in an IMAP installation, how can you use php's imap_search() method to retrieve only the new messages from the server?  There are a few other similar posts on here that ended up as dead ends, or users suggesting to check the message id against a stored database, but no clear way to pull only new messages from a POP3 mail server without having to pull all messages and loop through each one to see if it's new.

I tried setting a flag using the following:

```
$status = imap_setflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen \\Flagged", ST_UID);
```

AND using this to retrieve:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
```

Comment: Pop3 does not support searching, does not support flags.  There is no concept of a SEEN message in POP3, only messages you have and messages you don't.

Comment: Right.  I guess what I'm trying to understand is how email clients connect and are able to pull recent messages without looping through ALL messages to check to see if it has been downloaded yet.  Surely there is a better method, as an inbox of a few hundred thousand emails could take a long time to loop through when fetching new messages from the server.

Comment: As an alternative, are the email numbers always linked to the same emails?  Ie: if we do `for($emails as $email_number){  }` would each $email_number always correlate with the same email?  Or does this change when messages are deleted & re assigned?

Comment: The UIDL command in POP gives every message a unique identifier.  Unfortunately, you have to download the while list.  POP3 is terrible at handling large mailboxes for this reason.  It was designed as a download-and-delete protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the way POP3 is designed to work makes it a terrible candidate for PHP scraping.  Most clients delete messages from the server after download, and only the recent messages are left on the server (ideally one machine would be pulling from a POP server, there is no labeling or statusing that multiple devices can pick up)

Unfortunately, unless anyone else decides to chime in, it appears that the only way to quickly pull new messages without looping through all the old messages is to **delete the message from the server after download.**